# Calendar on various API

Tags: android, events, calendar, uri

I have problem with adding events to Android Calendar.
My minimum SDK version is 7. I use Intent to add event, but problems is with various API.
I use this:

```
             String eventUriString;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7)
     eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
    else  eventUriString = "content://calendar/events";

    ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

    eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1); 
    eventValues.put("title", "title");
    eventValues.put("description", desc);
    eventValues.put("eventLocation", "");

    long endDate = startDate + 1000 * 60 * 60; 

    eventValues.put("dtstart", MyClass.getDate());
    eventValues.put("dtend", endDate);

    eventValues.put("eventStatus", 0); 
    eventValues.put("visibility", 2); 
    eventValues.put("transparency", 0); 

    eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 0); 

    Uri eventUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues);
    long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
```

to Edit some events I use:

```
String calendarUriBase = null;
            long id = MyEvents.getID(p);  //something ID from my another class
        Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
        Cursor managedCursor = null;
        try {
            managedCursor = managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // eat
        }

        if (managedCursor != null) {
            calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
        } else {
            calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
            try {
                managedCursor = managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // eat
            }

            if (managedCursor != null) {
                calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
            }

        }

        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();

        event.put("title", "new Title");

        Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse(calendarUriBase+"events");
        Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, id);

        getContentResolver().update(eventUri, event, null, null);
```

and it work on my phone (SE X8 with Android 2.3.7) but doesn't work on SDK 14.

Is anywhere universal code, which I can use to add events to Calendar Android works on every various SDK? I have no idea how it make. I must use API 7 because my manager want. Have you any ideas how do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ICS a new Calendar API is introduced so your code will not work in ICS. 
[New Public APIs in ICS](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/ics-and-non-public-apis.html)

In order to support adding events to all calendars you can change your code like this -

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                saveCalendarEventICS();
            }
            else {
                int cal_id = getCalendar_ID();
                if(cal_id != 0){
                    saveCalendarEvent(cal_id);
                }
            }

private int getCalendar_ID() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int calendar_id         = 0;
            String[] projection     = new String[] { "_id", "name" };
            String selection        = "selected=1";
            String path             = "calendars";
            Cursor calendarCursor   = getCalendarCursor(projection, selection, path);

            if (calendarCursor != null && calendarCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int nameColumn      = calendarCursor.getColumnIndex("name");
                int idColumn        = calendarCursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
                do {
                    String calName  = calendarCursor.getString(nameColumn);
                    String calId    = calendarCursor.getString(idColumn);
                    if (calName != null /*&& calName.contains("Test")*/) {
                        calendar_id = Integer.parseInt(calId);
                    }
                } while (calendarCursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return calendar_id;
        }

private void saveCalendarEventICS() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
             .setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event")
             .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, frsttime)
             .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, sncdtime)
             .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY , false) // just included for completeness
             .putExtra(Events.TITLE, vl_hldr[0])
             .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, vl_hldr[2])
             .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, vl_hldr[1])
             .putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=10") 
             .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
             .putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE)
             .putExtra(Events.ALLOWED_REMINDERS, "METHOD_DEFAULT")
             .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
            startActivity(intent);
        }


private void saveCalendarEvent(int calid) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//Create the event here -----------


                Uri newEvent;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
                    //newEvent = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
                    newEvent = ctx.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), event);

                    if (newEvent != null) {
                        long id = Long.parseLong( newEvent.getLastPathSegment() );
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put( "event_id", id );
                        values.put( "method", 1 );
                        values.put( "minutes", 15 ); // 15 minuti

                        getContentResolver().insert( Uri.parse( "content://com.android.calendar/reminders" ), values );
                    }
                }
                else {
                    newEvent = ctx.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), event);

                    if (newEvent != null) {
                        long id = Long.parseLong( newEvent.getLastPathSegment() );
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put( "event_id", id );
                        values.put( "method", 1 );
                        values.put( "minutes", 15 ); // 15 minuti

                        getContentResolver().insert( Uri.parse( "content://calendar/reminders" ), values );
                    }
                }

            }catch(Exception ee){}

        }
```

Comment: Can you up vote me & also mark right as this the right answer please.

Comment: @kongo, do mark this answer as accepted as it will make others consider it.@Chinmoy- your solution worked! thanks :)

Comment: this will work (i upvoted too), but as a note, it only grabs the last calendarID, which may or may not be the calendar you want in the case of multiple calendars

Comment: How can I get google accounts calendar events also in list view.By using this code I can get only calendar events.

Comment: What is getCalendarCursor(String[], String, String) ??

Comment: @ user2841300 in order to get Google Calendar Events you have to use google api for fetching events or datas from Google Calendar.